# Bluetooth low energy services on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to figure out what services and characteristics are included inside various bluetooth low energy beacons. I am using an existing [application](https://github.com/cez801/BluetoothLeGatt), which lists each service name, along with its UUID.

I added mainly all the services into the `SampleGattAttributes` file, like follows:

```
    public static String USER_DATA_SERVICE = "0000181C-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
    public static String WEIGHT_SCALE_SERVICE = "0000181D-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
    attributes.put("0000181c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "user data service");
    attributes.put("0000181d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "weight scale service");
...
```

The problem is it never shows the name of the service. Besides, I found some UUIDs that does not exist on Bluetooth low energy list.

exp: b0702880-a295-a8ab-f734-031a98a512de

Can anyone tell me what service is that? or at least how can i figure it out? 
Thank you

Comment: what bluetooth device are you using? some devices have custom services not listed in the GATT specifications: https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx

Comment: a Galaxy S3.. all these services in the link you posted are registered in my example :/